# Java BigDecimal.round()

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am trying to round a BigDecimal value to the nearest 1000 using the below code

```
BigDecimal oldValue = new BigDecimal("791232");

BigDecimal newValue=oldValue.round(new MathContext(3,
            RoundingMode.UP));

System.out.println("Old -------   "+oldValue.intValue());
System.out.println("New-------   "+newValue.intValue());
```

This works fine for the above input. the result is below

> Old------>791232
>
> New------>792000

But the code not working for input 
< 1,00,000  (e.g  79123)  and input > 10,00,000 (e.g 7912354)

[image: Actual and Expected Result]

One more point noticed that if we change the precision  from 3 to 2  as below

```
new MathContext(2,RoundingMode.UP)
```

then it is working for input < 1,00,000.

Please help

Comment: Can you format this a bit so the input, actual output and expected output values are clear, for each particular setup you tried?

Comment: Why would you not expect 79123 to round to 79200, when you specify a precision of 3?  Also, I'm not duplicating the 8080000 result.

Comment: The precision is the number of digits of precision e.g. 1.234 rounded to 3 digits is 1.23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also you can update your code to it:

```
BigDecimal newValue = oldValue.round(new MathContext(oldValue.precision() - 3,
                        RoundingMode.CEILING));
```

Answer (score 5):

No need to divide/multiply by 1000, You just forgot to [set the scale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-)

```
oldValue.setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP);
```

after that the code is working as you wish:

```
BigDecimal oldValue = new BigDecimal("79123");
oldValue = oldValue.setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP);
BigDecimal newValue = oldValue.round(new MathContext(3, RoundingMode.UP));

System.out.println("Old -------   " + oldValue.intValue());
System.out.println("New-------   " + newValue.intValue());
```

the output:

> Old -------   79123
>
> New-------   79200

and

> Old -------   7912113
>
> New-------   7920000

Comment: Why is `setScale` required? It ought to have no effect whatsoever when called after the constructor since the API Javadoc says "The scale of the returned BigDecimal will be the number of digits in the fraction, or zero if the string contains no decimal point".

Comment: Done this change but not working. same result as before

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou if you do not set the scale and you have stuff beyond the decimal point it could affect your rounding

Answer (score 1):

If you want to round to the *nearest* 1000, you shouldn't use `RoundingMode.UP`, which is

> Rounding mode to round away from zero.

You want to use `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` which is:

> Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up.

Also I would suggest to use scale parameter as ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ suggested.

[Docs for rounding mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your precision is responsible for the digits count of the left side of your number. So to fix this, take the overall length and subtract the your expected precision.

The resulting code is:

```
BigDecimal oldValue = new BigDecimal("77252");
int expectedPrecision = 3;
int length = oldValue.precision() - expectedPrecision;

BigDecimal newValue=oldValue.round(new MathContext(length, RoundingMode.UP));

System.out.println("Old -------   "+oldValue.intValue());
System.out.println("New-------   "+newValue.intValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do rounds to the number of digits of precision e.g.

1.2345 rounded to 3 digits of precision is 1.23

If you want to round to the nearest 1000, you can do;

- divide by 1000
- round to the nearest whole number
- multiply by 1000

Answer (score 0):

The `MathContext` precision property is the number of digits to use (i.e. the number of significant figures). To round to a specific number of decimal places, use `setScale` with a positive scale; and use a negative scale if you want to round to a power of 10 - in your case, use -3 to round to 1000. Also, as Rumid quite rightly said, if you want to round to the *nearest* 1000 (not *up* to the next 1000) then use RoundingMode.HALF_UP (or RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN if you prefer):

```
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("7725232");
    b = b.setScale(-3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(b.intValue());
```